# Failed to find data source: delta in Python environment

Tags: unit-testing, pyspark, databricks, delta-lake

Following: https://docs.delta.io/latest/quick-start.html#python

I have installed delta-spark and run:

```
from delta import *

builder = pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder.appName("MyApp") \
    .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension") \
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog")

spark = spark = configure_spark_with_delta_pip(builder).getOrCreate()
```

However when I run:

```
data = spark.range(0, 5)
data.write.format("delta").save("/tmp/delta-table")
```

the error states: delta not recognised

& if I run

```
DeltaTable.isDeltaTable(spark, "packages/tests/streaming/data")
```

It states: TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable

It seemed that I could run these commands locally (such as unit tests) without Maven or running it in a pyspark shell? It would be good to just see if I am missing a dependency?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just install `delta-spark` PyPi package using `pip install delta-spark` (it will pull pyspark as well), and then refer to it.

Or you can add a configuration option that will fetch Delta package. It's `.config("spark.jars.packages", "io.delta:delta-core_2.12:<delta-version>")`.   For Spark 3.1 Delta versions is 1.0.0 (see [releases mapping docs](https://docs.delta.io/latest/releases.html) for more information).

I have an [example of using Delta tables in unit tests](https://github.com/alexott/spark-playground/blob/master/testing/src/python/test-delta.py) (please note, that import statement is in the function definition because Delta package is loaded dynamically):

```py
import pyspark
import pyspark.sql
import pytest
import shutil
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

delta_dir_name = "/tmp/delta-table"

@pytest.fixture
def delta_setup(spark_session):
    data = spark_session.range(0, 5)
    data.write.format("delta").save(delta_dir_name)
    yield data
    shutil.rmtree(delta_dir_name, ignore_errors=True)

def test_delta(spark_session, delta_setup):
    from delta.tables import DeltaTable
    deltaTable = DeltaTable.forPath(spark_session, delta_dir_name)
    hist = deltaTable.history()
    assert hist.count() == 1
```

environment is [initialized via pytest-spark](https://github.com/alexott/spark-playground/blob/master/testing/pytest.ini):

```
[pytest]
filterwarnings =
  ignore::DeprecationWarning
spark_options =
  spark.sql.extensions: io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension
  spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog: org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog
  spark.jars.packages: io.delta:delta-core_2.12:1.0.0
  spark.sql.catalogImplementation: in-memory
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, I found after clearing the cache of my pipenv environment and then installing pyspark=3.1.0 it worked

Comment: How can I find the "delta-version" value to form the `.config("spark.jars.packages", "io.delta:delta-core_2.12:<delta-version>")` config? For the spark version 3.2.2 I am running currently, it can be 1.1 or above, but I guess only one value works :P

Comment: the releases & their Spark versions are listed here: https://docs.delta.io/latest/releases.html - then check Maven Central: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.delta/delta-core